# NetCDF uses twice the memory when reading part of data. Why? How to rectify it?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, netcdf4

I have 2 fairly large datasets (~47GB) stored in a netCDF file. The datasets have three dimensions: time, s, and s1. The first dataset is of shape (3000,2088,1000) and the second is of shape (1566,160000,25). Both datasets are equal in size. The only difference is their shape. Since my RAM size is only 32GB, I am accessing the data in blocks.

For the first dataset, when I read the first ~12GB chunk of data, the code uses almost twice the amount of memory. Whereas, for the second, it uses just the amount of memory as that of the chunk (12GB). Why is this happening? How do I stop the code from using more than what is necessary?

Not using more memory is very important for my code because my algorithm's efficiency hinges on the fact that every line of code uses just enough memory and not more. Also, because of this weird behaviour, my system starts swapping like crazy. I have a linux system, if that information is useful. And I use python 3.7.3 with netCDF 4.6.2

This is how I am accessing the datasets,

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
dat = Dataset('dataset1.nc')
dat1 = Dataset('dataset2.nc')
chunk1 = dat.variables['data'][0:750] #~12GB worth of data uses ~24GB RAM memory
chunk2 = dat1.variables['data'][0:392] #~12GB worth of data uses ~12GB RAM memory
```

Comment: Very hard to tell without access to the data. One possibility is that one of the files is a zipped Netcdf but the other is not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.